# Passing a variable line by line into another command in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I have code that reads a txt file and is supposed to read the lines from it into a command. Then, the output of that command should also be read line by line into another command. My outer loop works (I have tested it using echo) but my nested loop does not:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do

    folder="$(aws s3 ls s3://a-bucket/users/ --recursive | grep ${p} | cut -c 32-)"

    while read -r line
    do
        aws s3 cp s3://a-bucket/"$line" 'c:/users/basud/desktop/testerData' --recursive
    done <<< "$folder"

done < testIDs.txt
```

The output from the first line that gets read into "folder" looks like this for each line of testIDs.txt:

```
users/3e8c95b4-c5ee-4edc-954e-6d988d30557e/111BEF99-5AB6-486A-ABD5-A4682CE0D491-LEFT.zip
users/3e8c95b4-c5ee-4edc-954e-6d988d30557e/111BEF99-5AB6-486A-ABD5-A4682CE0D491-RIGHT.zip
```

I want to pass each line of "folder" into the aws command after "a-bucket/" to add to the path name. I keep getting no output. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `done < <(aws s3 ls ...)`

Comment: One way to debug this is for you to add an `echo` before that `aws` line so you can see what the command looks like. Something like `echo aws s3 cp s3://a-bucket/"$line" 'c:/users/basud/desktop/testerData' --recursive`.

Comment: @choroba Can you explain your comment?

Comment: @choroba interesting answer but no dice when I ran the code =/
I am assuming the "done" in your comment is the one that precedes "$folder" in my original code

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work

```
$ folder="$(echo 1; echo 2)"; while read -r line; do echo "line: $line"; done <<< "$folder"
line: 1
line: 2
```

But in your case I would use this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://a-bucket/users/ --recursive | grep ${p} | cut -c 32- |
while read -r line
do
    aws s3 cp s3://a-bucket/"$line" 'c:/users/basud/desktop/testerData' --recursive
done
```

To debug your original script (or any other), run it with `bash -x`.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work either =/ Here's the code I ran:

`#!/bin/bash

while read p; do
    
    aws s3 ls s3://a-bucket/users/ --recursive | grep ${p} | cut -c 32- |
    while read -r line
    do
        echo $line
        aws s3 cp s3://a-bucket/"$line" 'c:/users/basud/desktop/testerData' --recursive
    done 
    
done < testIDs.txt`

Comment: Without line breaks that is impossible to read. Try to run it with `bash -x` and append the output to the question. Or run your original code with `bash -x` and append the output to the question.